Proving the Feynman-Kac formula
I am studying the construction of the construction of the Wiener measure in Reed and Simon Vol2.
By the construction of the measure, it follows that for any continuous, bounded function $f$ on $R^d$, that
$ \int_{\Omega} f(\gamma(t))d\mu_x(\gamma)=\int_{R^d}p(x,y,t)f(y)dy$,
where $\Omega$ is the space of all paths, $\mu_x$ is the Wiener measure and $p$ the heat kernel. Now they extend this equality to the square integrable functions $L^2(R^d)$. They use the density of continuous functions of compact support in $L^2(R^d)$ and the dominated convergence theorem. While this step is clear to me for the right hand side of the equation, it is not for the left hand side. Let $g_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions of compact support that converges in $L^2$-norm to some $h \in L^2(R^d)$, then we know by the above equation
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} g_n(\gamma(t))d\mu_x(\gamma)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{R^d}p(x,y,t)g_n(y)dy=\int_{R^d}p(x,y,t)h(y)dy$.
But to apply the dominated convergence theorem on the left hand side, i first need to know, that
$ \int_{\Omega} h(\gamma(t))d\mu_x(\gamma)$
exist. How can one see this?
